# Regular Expression C# IsMatch()

Tags: c#, regex

I try to use regular expression to check if a string contains only: 0-9, A-Z, a-z, \, / or -.
I used `Regex validator = new Regex(@"[0-9a-zA-Z\-/]*");` and no matter what string I introduce is valid.

The check look like this: `if(!validator.IsMatch(myString))`

What's wrong?

Comment: thr problem is, your regex matches every string, as you state in the question.

Comment: which strings are valid? Or which string are you trying to match as invalid?

Comment: Star operator means "match zero or more times". Every string contains every character class at least zero times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want. I believe your pattern should be

```
new Regex(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z\\\-/]*$");
```

The `^` and `$` symbols are anchors that match the beginning and end of the string, respectively. Without those, the pattern would match any strings that contain any character in that class. With them, it matches strings that *only* contain characters in that class.

You also specified you wanted to include backslash characters, but the original pattern had `\-` in the character class. This is simply an escape sequence for the hyphen within the character class. To also include backslash in the character class you need to specify that separately (escaped as well). So the resulting character class has `\\` (backslash) followed by `\-` (hyphen).

Now, this will still match empty strings because `*` means "zero-or-more". if you want to only match non-empty strings use:

```
new Regex(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z\\\-/]+$");
```

The `+` means "one-or-more".

Comment: @LearnByReading The `+` means the expression will match one or more instances of the previous character, character class, or group. It's called a [*quantifier*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If I write a Regex of the form

```
"[some character class]*"
```

it will match every string. Every string contains 0 to many of a character class.

Perhaps you wanted to use

```
new Regex(@"[0-9a-zA-Z\-/]+")
```

to specify 1 to many of your character class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `*`

```
new Regex(@"[0-9a-zA-Z\-/]+");
```